# How can i download Postgres 9.5.7?

Tags: postgresql

How can i install PostgreSQL 9.5.7 i install PostgreSQL 9.5 but then only have an option to upgrade to 9.5.12.

Comment: Why would you want to install a release with known bugs that are fixed in the most recent version?

Comment: I need to test a piece of software against a already existing database.

Comment: Do you need to test the known bugs as well? If not, 9.5.12 will behave the same way as 9.5.7

Comment: https://www.enterprisedb.com/versions/postgresql-959